# Как можно по другому активировать эти камера шейки, не через use pawn control rotation в Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, камера

В используемых мной анимациях камера шейки сделаны не через блюпринт камера Шейк, а они встроены в сами анимации. Там есть одна кость hero-camera.

Так вот, вот эти шейки воспроизводятся на этой кости. Чтобы эти камера шейки активировались, то мне надо к сожалению деактивировать use pawn control rotation в камере перса.

Было бы неплохо, если бы я понял, как можно по другому активировать эти камера шейки, не через use pawn control rotation.

Хз, что делать. Может, кто знает?

Еще я заметил одну деталь. Допустим, у меня включён по стандарту use pawn control rotation, но в чем прикол этого камера шейка встроенного в сами анимации: когда камера персонажа расположена от первого лица, то камера Шейк как бы есть, но его сила (интенсивность) настолько мала, что не годится, но если отодвинуть камеру персонажа по вектору вперёд, на определённую дистанцию, например сделать вид от третьего лица, то сила шатания камеры увеличивается в разы, в итоге получается сила шатания, как мне нужно.

Первое фото это от первого лица (камера Шейк очень слабый), второе фото от третьего лица (камера Шейк очень сильный, как мне и нужно).

В итоге мне как то надо сделать, чтобы сила камера шейка была, как в третьем лице, а расположение самой камеры было от первого лица. Надеюсь, Кто-то в курсе, почему так происходит и сможет подсказать, куда копать. Так же покажу саму кость.

Последние две картинки это моя кость на которую я закрепил камеру персонажа. К слову, только на этой кости воспроизводятся шейки.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя видно компонент камеры приаттачен к мешу, поэтому она присоединена к кости и двигается с ней. Просто открепи её от меша, прикрепи к GetRootComponent()